# Call a POST rest api with AddJsonBody method vs. AddObject method

Tags: restsharp

I am using RestSharp to do a REST API client application.  If the format of request body (pay load) for a POST Rest Api call is JSON, I would like to know when I should use RestRequest.AddJsonBody() method and when RestRequest.AddObject() method. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To send a JSON payload, use AddJsonBody. AddObject will extract name-value pairs from the object and add them as parameters.